# Idea IntelliJ crash issue on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, crash, intellij-idea

I recently installed Idea IntelliJ 10.0.3 on my Mac Snow Leopard. Whenever I try opening a project, IntelliJ starts indexing and in the process crashes!! It happens everytime.

I have Java 1.6.0_15 on my machine. I am not sure if this happens due to specific version of Java or due to a problem with my settings on IntelliJ.

Anybody experienced this before? Any fixes?

Comment: Java 1.6.0_15? Java 1.6.0_24 is what you should use. Update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK 1.6.0_15 is known to crash because of GC bug, installing Apple Java Update is known to resolve this problem (current version is 1.6.0_26). Hardware problem mentioned by @xbit is also possible, but less likely.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well.  It turned out to be bad memory in my case. Run Memtest if you are experiencing frequent crashes.  Turn computer off, then hold down Command-S while turning on.  This will boot you to single user mode.  Then run "memtest all 2".